# CSS: Table extending popup, even with width/max-width set

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to figure out why I can't set a width for this issue I'm having. I can set a width, but it's not doing anything. And, I'm not even sure why this element is extending the popup in the first place (also, I feel like setting a width should not be necessary here).

See image below (on the left side, Customer Airports). Notice the white rectangular boxes sticking out.

[image: my issue]

If you are having trouble seeing the image clearly, just right click the image and open the URL in a new browser.

This is a td with an ID of icao_input. Frankly I hate using tables here but I've been asked not to tamper with the format.

The HTML:

```html
<div id='cust_airport_popup_container_small'>
  <div id='page_title'>Customer Airports - Add an airport</div>
  <script>
    var fcn="confirmAirport()";
  </script>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="icao_label">Airport ICAO</td>
      <td id="icao_input">
        <input type='textfield' id='ICAO' name='ICAO' class='textfield_class_inline_small' onkeydown='hideErrorMsg(); enterSubmission(event, fcn)' value='' maxlength='4'>
        &nbsp;(4-letter code)
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td id="icao_buttons">
        <input type="button" class="btn" value="Cancel" onclick="cancelBox()">
        <input type="button" class="btn" value="Add Airport" onclick="confirmAirport()">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table><br>
  <div id="ca_error_msg" class="error_message"></div></div>
```

Where are these white rectangular boxes coming from in the first place? And how do I account for them (aka, get rid of them)?

Any input on the matter is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried these code, but there is no css file, so I cann't find out what's the error.

It seems that the white line is table border, you can try table { border-width: 0px; } to avoid it

Comment: Yeah tried that thinking it would work (and even did the same for tr and td). But the issue was our main.css file. table tr,td in there have a white border so that was causing the issue. With css it's always something obvious :x

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1

```
#cust_airport_popup_container_small{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

## Solution 2

Might not work

```
#cust_airport_popup_container_small table{
    width:100%;
}
```